Bubble effect as filling in a rectangle
I would like to be able to add bubbles in a rectangle, a bit like champagne bubbles: I saw that the pst-labo package allows it but I don't know how I could reproduce it in tikz.


Normally you should always show what you have tried or at least supply compilable code for the part that is needed to show the solution (here it is the cup/rectangle).

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\fill[cyan!60] {[rounded corners=0.5cm](-2,3) -- (-2,0) -- (2,0)} -- (2,3) -- cycle;
\draw (0,5) ellipse[x radius=2, y radius=0.2];
\draw[rounded corners=0.5cm] (-2,5) -- (-2,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,5);
\foreach \i in {1,...,100}
  \draw[fill=cyan!50] (1.6*rand,2.2*rnd+0.2) circle[radius=0.12*rnd+0.05];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


